# Declared varchar in where condition

Tags: sql, where-clause, declare

I want to pass declared variables to where.

For example I have a table `#test`:

```
ID Amount
1  100
2  50
3  20
4  40 
5  150
```

I want to do something like that:

```
declare @id varchar(11) = '(1, 4, 5)'
select * from #test where IDNumber  in @id
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Comma separated items and SQL don't go well together. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Use datatypes *designed* to store multiple values (table-values parameters/variables, XML, JSON) rather than stuffing things into *strings* and then facing headaches because you need to pull them back apart if you want SQL to *treat* them as multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table valued user defined function as given below. There are many examples available online.

[Convert comma separated list to Table valued function](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html)

this will be giving you good results and better approach, than dynamic sql code.

Once you have the function `dbo.split(@string NVARCHAR(4000),',')` then use them in the JOIN as given below.

```
declare @id varchar(11) = '1, 4, 5'
select t.* from #test as t
JOIN dbo.Split(@id,',') AS csv
ON t.id = csv.data;
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments you'd be better off using another datatype.

But if you really did want to do it like your example, you could use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @ids VARCHAR(32) = '1,4,5';
DECLARE @result TABLE (ID INT, Amount INT);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'  SELECT ID, Amount
    FROM #test
    WHERE ID IN (' + @ids + ');';

PRINT @sql;

INSERT @result
EXEC(@sql);

SELECT*
FROM @result;
```

The results are placed into a table variable if you need to use them again in your script, if not you can just `EXEC` the sql

Answer (score 1):

Try the following-:

```
        declare @id varchar(11) = '(1, 4)'
        declare @sql nvarchar(max)
        set @sql='select * from TABLE_NAME where id  in '+ @id
        EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql
```

SQL Server 2014